# How to read a string variable in php as $_GET or $_POST?

Tags: php

How can I read a string as query like when you go to https://www.youtube.com/get_vide_info?v={{video_id}}

it will give an information as a query ( if you put it in $_GET ) the PHP will read it manually!

How can I read it without passing it in $_GET like if there is a function

Example:

```
<?php


$s = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/get_vide_info?v={{video_id}}');

// for example it returned status=failed&error=404&reason=copyright

//how can read status and error and reason

// for example 
echo "reject reason $s->reason ";
echo "status $s->status ";
```

Comment: whats the problem in reading from request?? ie $_GET or something $_SERVER. also how you wish to get data parsing string or request object?

Comment: *( must read )* ??

Comment: RohitS you don't understand the question. any way i got the answer from 3161993

Comment: removed non-related tag and some other stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy option is to use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), which you can access as array, if you want as object you have to convert it into object.

```
// arg1 => query string
// arg2 => output array
parse_str($your_string_response, $output);

echo $output['reason'];
echo $output['status'];
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat test.php 
<?php

$string = "status=failed&error=404&reason=copyright";
parse_str($string, $output);
print_r($output); // as array
print_r((object)$output); // as object

?>
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [status] => failed
    [error] => 404
    [reason] => copyright
)
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => failed
    [error] => 404
    [reason] => copyright
)
```

Comment: @JamalAbo yes, but if you just want one element, access like `$output['reason']`, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

you can read queryString with a magic field $_GET['NameOfQuery'];

```php
$s=array("status"=>$_GET['status'],
"error"=>$_GET['error'],
"reason"=>$_GET['reason']);

// out
echo "reject reason:".$s['reason'];
echo "status :".$s['status'];
echo "error :".$s['error'];;
```